Use Azure Phi3 model inference endpoint using managed identity
For one of my python apps we call a deployed Phi3 model with API key retreived from a key vault to summarize a document.
As a good practice, I wanted to check if we can use managed identity with Phi3 as I use when calling other models.

add what you tried so far.

yes, it is possible. See my test in the azure portal. the key call out is that the phi model are using ML under the hood. the endpoints are different to OpenAI model endpoints, it would be hosted in xxxxx.eastus2.inference.ml.azure.com/score
Use the pencil icon to select auth type: apikey is default, you can choose AADToken for oauth. there is a small delay in applying the auth type change

Once set, the test tab will start to use oauth token.

